# Moved Wordpress and CivCRM to new server recently

Tags: wordpress, migration

Recently I moved my Wordpress Install with CiviCRM over to a new server. I changed the path location in civicrm.settings.php file to reflect the new location. The front end of appears as if nothing is wrong but on the admin dashboard this appears:

> Warning: require_once(/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/xxx_xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
>   on line 399
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/home/xxx_xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/home/xxx_xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in
>   /home/xxx_xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
>   on line 399

If I deactivate CiviCRM, everything else appears to work fine, but I need this to work for this site. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's on line 399?

Comment: @ChristianWach The code is 'require_once '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';'

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've a couple of hangovers! These are usually in the CiviCRM Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs, and Administer > System Settings > Directories pages. Update those, clear cache, and you should be good to go!